# How do I create an Alert in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, slds

I'm looking for the best practice to fire a simple Confirm, Prompt or Alert from a component using the LDS (and use the response).

It feels like it should be simple question but I can't find an example.

Comment: Me too.  Good question and for in house development and building prototypes I am not interested in building a custom confirm dialog.  I also hope that someday LDS will include this basic UI building block.

Answer (score 2):

There are notification components documented.

You can roll your own JavaScript here as per specification

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/notifications/

You can use one of the toasts or prompt depending on your need.

Please note all code has to be custom .

Comment: Yes, I had read that information.  What I am trying to understand is the best way to initiate the 'alert', and how to handle the fact that the user has clicked OK or Cancel

Comment: Are you using component framework or visualforce ? You will need to throw the buttons there and identify via the button name

Comment: I am writing a lightning component

Comment: Have you started with a code for same that I can look and help you here .

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care too much about the looks (LDS) you can leverage the 'normal' javascript alerts by calling them from your lightning component controller:

Component code:

```
<lightning:buttonIcon name="remove" variant="bare" size="small" iconName="utility:delete" onclick="{!c.removeItem}" alternativeText="remove item" />
```

Component controller code:

```
({
    removeItem: function(component, event, helper) {
        // show a confirm
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")){
           // perform custom logic here    

        }
    },
})
```

Comment: Exactly what I need to build a MVP.  I was disheartened to know I'd have to build a custom confirm dialog for this most basic UI component.  Happy to know the confirm dialog is there and it is more than sufficient for in house development.

Answer (score 0):

[force:showToast](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_showToast.htm) has been made available since this question was posted a while back, imo, it is the easiest way to display a notification based on a user action.

```
showToast : function(component, event, helper) {
    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    toastEvent.setParams({
        "title": "Success!",
        "message": "The record has been updated successfully."
    });
    toastEvent.fire();
}
```

There is also the [lightning:notificationsLibrary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_lightning_notificationsLibrary.htm) which is basically a SLDS modal component that can be created dynamically to display a message, It is available since API v41.